# How to expose directive property to be used inside directive content

Tags: angular

https://plnkr.co/edit/6Rf11kBMpXH09tbksj1J?p=preview

app.component.ts:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  list$: Observable<any>;

  constructor () {
    let list = [
    {color : 'red', op: 70},
    {color : 'green', op: 80},
    {color : 'blue', op: 60},
    {color : 'yellow', op: 50},
    {color : 'black', op: 40}
    ];
    this.list$ = Observable.from(list);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div direc [data]="list$">
     List fetched data
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.color}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

The directive code is:

```
    import { Input, Directive, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[direc]'
})
export class DirecDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input()
  data;

  items: any[];

  constructor() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.data.take(3).toArray().subscribe(data => this.items = data);
    console.log(this.items);
  }

}
```

**I cannot access the items list in the <li></li>. How to access the decorator property items?**

What I've done is to pass Observable to the directive. In ngAfterViewInit method I have the Observable and I use it to get the data. The data is assigned to directive **item** property and I try to use it inside the directive content. There are not errors in the browser console and the items are listed successfully in the ngAfterViewInit method.
In the plunker is more simplified:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6Rf11kBMpXH09tbksj1J?p=preview

The *ngFor is directive inside the direc directive. Should have access to the direc directive items, but it doesn't. Or at least there is nothing rendered.

Comment: you seem to be passing `data` and then never using it, while never initializing `items` to a value at all.  Of course, that *might* be in the redacted code, which makes the redacted code **directly relevant** to the question.

Comment: OK . Thanks. Will edit the code with more details.

Comment: @Claies I init the items in the ngAfterViewInit method. Regards

Comment: There is no observable in the Plunker. What is the expected behavior? How can the problem be reproduced?

Comment: The `items` is not available there, because the properties of the directive are not in scope there. What you can do use using `exportAs` `@Directive({
  selector: '[direc]',
  exportAs: 'direc',
})
export class DirecDirective ... {` make it available to a template variable `<div #d="direc" direc [data]="list">` and then access it using that variable `<li *ngFor="let item of direc.items">{{item.color}}</li>`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/P8jH86nf41uIpYWSrxQG?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `items` is not available, because the properties of the directive are not in scope there. What you can do use `exportAs`

```
@Directive({ 
  selector: '[direc]', 
  exportAs: 'direc', 
}) export class DirecDirective ... {
```

make it available as a template variable

```
<div #d="direc" direc [data]="list">
```

and then access it using that variable

```
<li *ngFor="let item of direc.items">{{item.color}}</li>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/P8jH86nf41uIpYWSrxQG?p=preview)